# Visual Studio - Automatically convert new lines in code when pasting

Tags: visual-studio

Due to Unity's newer version not supporting MonoDevelop any longer, I've just made the switch to Microsoft Visual Studio. Now, on my current project I'm working with a lot of texts, which I have to copy from a word-document and save them in my code as strings.

In MonoDevelop there was this nice formatting feature where it would automatically format this:

`This is a title
This is some text after a forced new line`

into this string: "This is a title\nThis is some text after a forced new line"

This was very handy when working with texts and Visual Studio is just pasting it with the new line into my code, which then destroys the syntax like so:

public string Example =

`"This is a title
This is some text after a forced new line" (Syntax error)`

Any way to control the formatting and make it translate the new line from the copied text into code automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use verbatim strings that will allow you to continue the string on to a new line:

```
public string Example =
@"This is a title
This is some text after a forced new line";
```

This will allow you to keep any new-lines within the copied text.

This won't automatically escape double quotes within the copied text though which would need to be escaped by another double quote i.e. `This is some "quoted" text` should be

```
var s = @"This is some ""quoted"" text";
```

**Another Way**

You could also put all this text into a resource file. This would have the added benefit of keeping the code clean too.

For more info, check out [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/)

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is there also an option to still indent parts of the strings somehow? If I indent them, it will also show up in the app, of course. But, if I just use the @symbol before the string, parts of the string after the new line will be at the far left of the code, which is super ugly.

Comment: The only other way would be to put the strings in to a resource file. This would keep the code clean and keep all the text in one place.